# How to call private funtions in utility functions in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Following is the `util\util.js` file that I'm using in my project. I have used this to filter the array content. But I got some error like `undefined function filterList`. How can I call private functions inside a util function?

```
import React from 'react'

export default class {
  static list(jsonData, value) {
    jsonData.filter(filterList, value)
  }

  filterList = (item, value) => {
    return (item.value === value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried `jsonData.filter(this.filterList, value)` but it is not success

Comment: It's not *private*, but it's an *instance method*. You call static methods on the *class*. If the static method needs to access it, make it static too; it doesn't use `this`, so doesn't need to be an instance method.

Comment: I changed it as static like `static filterList = (item, value) => {`.  But still the response is `filterList` not defined.

Comment: Because it's a static method, you call static methods on the class. You need a class name to access the method on.

Answer (score 0):

Export an instance of the class instead of the class itself

```
class Utils{
  static list(jsonData, value) {
    jsonData.filter(filterList, value)
  }

  filterList = (item, value) => {
    return (item.value === value)
  }
}
export default Utils();
export  { Utils }
```